# What's an "upgraded connection" (in ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core

The docs for IIS request size limits mention an "upgraded connection" with no explanation as to what that means.

For example, the `MaxRequestBodySize` property of `IHttpMaxRequestBodySizeFeature` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.ihttpmaxrequestbodysizefeature?view=aspnetcore-5.0))

> The maximum allowed size of the current request body in bytes. When set to null, the maximum request body size is unlimited. This cannot be modified after the reading the request body has started. **This limit does not affect upgraded connections which are always unlimited.**

Comment: I guess this: [An upgraded connection is one that has been switched from HTTP to another protocol, such as WebSockets.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.maxconcurrentupgradedconnections?view=aspnetcore-5.0)